What power supply should I design for a wide range voltmeter?
I'm trying to make a 3 digit AC voltmeter that could display the voltage it draws it's power from. It should be able de measure voltage from 50-500 Vac or so and should mostly be used at around 230 Vac and 50 Hz whatever the voltage.
I've worked out all the measurement and display part and thought i could base the supply part on projects example I've found. The thing is that I'm really limited in space, the whole project should fit in a 30 mm diameter tube which is 58 mm long.
The example I was basing the power supply from was  using a capacitor reactance to limit the current followed by a diode bridge and finally a BJT transistor combined with a 12 V Zener diode as voltage regulator. Please note that I'm aware this is dangerous due to lack of isolation, the final project would be sufficiently protected and sealed.
The problem is that the power that the voltage regulator would have to dissipate would be huge for higher voltages and i don't have much space for a radiator. Plus the efficiency is miserable. I guess this kind of power supply are not made for variating voltages. That was a mistake from the beginner I am.
That brings me to my question:
What power supply should I design to match my needs in space, voltage and current?
I've seen that buck converter could be better for changing input voltage but I haven't seen one that could handle such a wide range. I would start to think that this project is not feasible if I haven't had seen it on the market.
Any other ideas or point of view are welcome, I think I have quite restrictive conditions and I would have to make sacrifices.

Linear regulators are not the way to go for this high of a voltage ratio. Use a switching converter. It may not be trivial to design one that can take such a wide input range, but it's definitely possible.

Please ask a specific question

The supply in the schematic is inherently extremely dangerous.  There is no galvanic isolation from the mains, and a single component failure exposes whatever an whoever is downstream to lethal voltages.

Please clarify ”Vca”. Do you mean Vac?

A variable AC supply is usually achieved by a variac

@AnalogKid You can use double insulation if you don't use isolation

The only "insulation" in the schematic is the C6 dielectric, and even that is bypassed.  Everything else is connected directly to the mains.  I know what double and reinforced insulations are, and they are not here.


I'm trying to make a 3 digit AC voltmeter that could display the voltage it draws it's power from. It should be able de measure voltage from 50Vca to 500Vca or so and should mostly be used at around 230Vca and 50Hz whatever the voltage.

It seems you are a beginner in electronics, so I would strongly recommend that you do not undertake building such a device on your own.  The circuit schematic you have presented is very dangerous; failure of a single component can either electrocute a person or start a fire.
Regarding the device you have described:  There are many of these devices already on the market, here are just two examples.
Many are DIN-rail mounted:

Link for image above:
https://www.se.com/au/en/product/15201/modular-digital-voltmeter-ivlt-230v-0-600v/
Here is one example that is 22mm in diameter:

Link for image above:
https://cnwstele.en.made-in-china.com/product/ldHtGKjMnRkg/China-Ad16-22vam-22mm-AC-50V-500V-0-100A-LED-Light-Digital-Voltage-Current-Meter-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Indicator.html

That brings me to my question: Does anybody have a clue on what kind of supply could match my needs ?

It seems you need 5Vdc at 40mA output (power = 200mW), fed from an AC voltage that can vary from 50VAC to 500VAC.  In that case, you should be able to find a complete power supply available from the market, here is one I found after just 1 minute of searching that is a very close match to your requirements:

Link for image above:
https://recom-power.com/pdf/Powerline_AC-DC/RAC05-K_480.pdf

The supply in the schematic is inherently extremely dangerous. There is no galvanic isolation from the mains, and a single component failure exposes whatever and whoever is downstream to lethal voltages.  Also, as you've found, using a capacitor as an AC voltage dropper is impractical at large voltage ranges.
If the total load is 5 V at 40 mA, the simple and safe solution is a USB wall wart.  Some are very small, and might fit in your space without modification.
